# Is there a version control or remote deploy program, or a combination of the two that would give me the features I need?

Tags: version-control

What I would like to do is to manage a set of mostly independent files across a lead server and different owners. Where I diverge from my limited understanding of version control is that unlike the source code of a single program, I want to track each individual file and its history, versions and branches separately and I don't particularly care about the version of the entire collection. Some of those branches will be long living but will have to be rebased on the lead files. I would also appreciate some sort of management tools that will let me review all the above information.

The owners and server don't have to be real owner and servers. In fact it would be better if they aren't, since the actual deployment is the least of my concerns. It can be just different folders with "owners" associated with them on the same hard drive if the program will allow it.

Is there such a program that will let me do this?

The reason I don't think traditional git workflow would do it for me is:
If I have 10 files over 10 owners, and each owner has 8 files on latest version and 2 files on an owner-specific fork, thats 10 different versions that are all valid. Then if one master file has to change I need to rebase the owner-specific forks on however many owners are affected and create new versions for them. If a file on a particular owner changes, that is fine. For that owner, that file should increment its version. Then I would still like to have an overview per file, to see for that file how its forked and where, and if it needs rebasing anywhere. I

EDIT: My question is similar to: [Version control system which keeps track of individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022627/version-control-system-which-keeps-track-of-individual-files)
but it had no satisfactory answers. I don't think traditional git usage with verrsioning for the entire set will help me since i can have so many permutations of forked files in the set over all the owners. Or at least I can't imagine this flow but feel free to change my mind.

Comment: You should really explain in more detail why a single Git repo will not work. Who has forked what? Where are the branches? Why will it not *Just Work* if the owners of these clones simply merge their stuff to your master branch when they (or you) want to?

Comment: I will be doing all the forking. The owners are basically different locations those files exist at. For each location, some files will need to be different and will evolve differently over time. The reason I dont want merges back to master is there are reasons why these files will need to be different than master on each location. With few exceptions, I don't want the master files to change.

Comment: So you basically have per-clone configuration data? Sounds like you should refactor your system to generate the configuration files from a tree of per-clone settings or something like that (Ansible, Puppet, etc?)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible, as it's not exactly configuration data. It's more like templates that then live and change on each location. I cannot generate them in advance. They just drift over time for legitimate reasons on each location

Comment: So how do they change over time? Will an individual clone want to check if upstream changed and merge the upstream changes when they have a chance? I'm thinking there may be some similarities to how software localization is performed (each target language is different, but when the upstream changes, they will eventually want to update accordingly) but also that we still don't have a good understanding of what exactly you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: I have to be vague on purpose unfortunately. Please bear with me. Files could be scripts to do a task. For a certain clones, the local circumstances have changed so the script also has changed. That script then still cares about possible bug fixes in the master script, but if the bugfix is in a branch of the script that doesn't even exist anymore, then it doesn't need to pull those changes. As long as I can somehow mark that this script is still up to date even though it was branched from an older master version. Does that make sense?

Comment: Vaguely, but I'm really tempted to vote to close as unclear / too broad. If you can't communicate your requirements, I don't think we can or want to try to satisfy them meaningfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For *pure per-file* history you can use now only CVS, this is, anyway The Bad Choice
2. In any case, in any current VCS (with changesets) you can easy get per-file history of change, thus - I can't see source of your troubles here (you follow "one changeset - one file" workflow even in multifile repository)
3. You can use (again) any VCS and "repository per file" methodology
4. For any VCS you can reference|use|have access to any revision of object in repo (HEAD or non-HEAD) and collect "superset" of repo with any mixed stuff (it's mostly question of your selected VCS)

I''ll implement your task on any of modern VCS from "Big Three" family easy, with just more or less handwork (easiest way - SVN with externals, most robust - Mercurial with guest-repo, lame and dirty - fashion Git with submodules)

You have to describe you task more technically in order to get more precise answer

Comment: Will these ways let me select an individual file and easily get information on how many different versions of that file exist, which location they live at, and get descriptions on why those versions were branched?

Comment: This gave me a lot of directions to study so I'm going to accept it unless another answer comes by.